# Create an array of all products whose value is less than 150

Tags: javascript, filter, array-filter

```js
var productMaster=[{id:'A441',name:'Pepsi',category:'Soft Drink', price:15, quantity:2},
{id:'B234',name:'Coke', category:'Soft Drink', price:10, quantity:8},
{id:'A617',name:'Mirinda', category:'Soft Drink', price:20, quantity:20},
{id:'B003',name:'Sprite', category:'Soft Drink', price:16, quantity:5},
{id:'B225',name:'Minute Maid', category:'Soft Drink', price:25, quantity:12},
{id:'A742',name:'5Star', category:'Chocloate', price:10, quantity:3},
{id:'B388',name:'Appy', category:'Soft Drink', price:35, quantity:9},
{id:'A899',name:'Gems', category:'Chocloate', price:12, quantity:11},
{id:'B635',name:'KitKat', category:'Chocloate', price:15, quantity:7},
{id:'B408',name:'Perk', category:'Chocloate', price:8, quantity:15},
{id:'A354',name:'Dairy Milk', category:'Chocloate', price:30, quantity:4}];

var arr1 = productMaster.filter(n => n.value=n.price*n.quantity && n.value<150);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));
```

> Value is defined as price * quantity and i am getting an empty array. i have to Create an array of all products whose value is less than 150.

Comment: can you use `.filter(n => n.price*n.quantity<150);` or is your result supposed to have an additional `value` property added to all the objects?

Comment: Just to filter ..no additional value property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```js
var productMaster=[{id:'A441',name:'Pepsi',category:'Soft Drink', price:15, quantity:2},
{id:'B234',name:'Coke', category:'Soft Drink', price:10, quantity:8},
{id:'A617',name:'Mirinda', category:'Soft Drink', price:20, quantity:20},
{id:'B003',name:'Sprite', category:'Soft Drink', price:16, quantity:5},
{id:'B225',name:'Minute Maid', category:'Soft Drink', price:25, quantity:12},
{id:'A742',name:'5Star', category:'Chocloate', price:10, quantity:3},
{id:'B388',name:'Appy', category:'Soft Drink', price:35, quantity:9},
{id:'A899',name:'Gems', category:'Chocloate', price:12, quantity:11},
{id:'B635',name:'KitKat', category:'Chocloate', price:15, quantity:7},
{id:'B408',name:'Perk', category:'Chocloate', price:8, quantity:15},
{id:'A354',name:'Dairy Milk', category:'Chocloate', price:30, quantity:4}]
    
  
var arr1 = productMaster.filter(n => n.price*n.quantity < 150);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to set the value to the quantity times the price, then get those whose value is below 150, you can use `map()` then `filter()`:

```js
var productMaster = [
  {id:'A441',name:'Pepsi',category:'Soft Drink', price:15, quantity:2},
  {id:'B234',name:'Coke', category:'Soft Drink', price:10, quantity:8},
  {id:'A617',name:'Mirinda', category:'Soft Drink', price:20, quantity:20},
  {id:'B003',name:'Sprite', category:'Soft Drink', price:16, quantity:5},
  {id:'B225',name:'Minute Maid', category:'Soft Drink', price:25, quantity:12},
  {id:'A742',name:'5Star', category:'Chocloate', price:10, quantity:3},
  {id:'B388',name:'Appy', category:'Soft Drink', price:35, quantity:9},
  {id:'A899',name:'Gems', category:'Chocloate', price:12, quantity:11},
  {id:'B635',name:'KitKat', category:'Chocloate', price:15, quantity:7},
  {id:'B408',name:'Perk', category:'Chocloate', price:8, quantity:15},
  {id:'A354',name:'Dairy Milk', category:'Chocloate', price:30, quantity:4}];

var arr1 = productMaster.map((n) => {
  n.value = n.price * n.quantity;
  return n;
}).filter(n => n.value < 150);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));
```